# setNeedDisplay still does not work

Tags: ios, objective-c, drawrect, setneedsdisplay

Previously I asked a question in stackoverflow and that is about `setNeedsDisplay` cannot work.
I am not a lazy guy and I have tried everything but it still cannot work.
Maybe I cannot find where is the problem.
Can anyone help me to find out the problem?

```
//viewcontroller.m
#import "ViewController.h"
@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize frequency;
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    hi = [[cro alloc]init];
    [self.view addSubview:hi];
    CGFloat fu = frequency.value;
    [hi changefreq:fu];
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
-(IBAction)change:(id)sender
{
    CGFloat fu = frequency.value;
    [hi changefreq:fu];
}
@end
//cro.m
#import "cro.h"

@implementation cro
@synthesize fffff;
CGFloat freee;
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}
-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 1);
    CGContextSetLineJoin(context, kCGLineJoinRound);
    NSLog(@"hi i am here %f",fffff);
    const CGFloat amplitude = 200/2;
    for(CGFloat x = 0; x < 600; x += 0.5)
    {
        CGFloat y = amplitude * cosf(2 * M_PI * (x / 600) * freee) + 200;
        if(x == 0)
            CGContextMoveToPoint(context, x, y);
        else
            CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, x, y);
    }
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [[UIColor greenColor] CGColor]);
    self.clearsContextBeforeDrawing = NO;
    CGContextStrokePath(context);
}
-(void)changefreq:(CGFloat)fre
{
    NSLog(@"fre= %f",fre);
    freee = fre;
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

@end
```

here is the project 
http://www.sendspace.com/file/lzt4b0

Comment: This is a very open ended question. Try to be specific and explain why it isn't working. For example, is `changefreq:` ever run? Is `change:` attached to some control (like a button)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You initialize your view by calling `[[cro alloc] init]`. Since you're not calling `initWithFrame:` this will result in a view with zero width and height. Calling `setNeedsDisplay` on such a view has no effect because there is nothing to display.

Change your first line in `viewDidLoad` to something like

```
hi = [[cro alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 320)];
```

(adjust the size as needed)

Alternatively, you might want to use the `cro` instance that you already have in your storyboard instead of instantiating a new one. The storyboard instance is the one you're seeing, the `hi` instance is actually invisible with your current code. (btw, if you expect other people to read your code, you might want to start using sensible variable and class names.)

Comment: OMG I SUCCESS I LOVE U <3

Comment: I can successfully update the drawrect but the old image is not cleaned. How to clean up the view?

Comment: Remove the `self.clearsContextBeforeDrawing = NO;` line.

Answer (score 0):

The following changes in ViewController.m ViewdidLoad method will do the fix

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    hi = [[cro alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(201, 58, 414, 571)];
    [self.view addSubview:hi];
    CGFloat fu = frequency.value;
    [hi changefreq:fu];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do the following it works for me:

- Use property instead of ivar

  - Now you access your `cro` instance through `self.cro`
  - Connect in your storyboard the view controller's outlet `cro` (there is already a property named like this in your uploaded project) with the subview
- Remove in `-[ViewController viewDidLoad:]` the lines where you create a new `cro` instance and add it as a subview to `self`
- Use in your `cro`-class the ivar `fffff` in `-[cro changefreq:]` and `-[cro drawRect:]`

(It's all copied from your uploaded project only with my changes)

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet cro *cro;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISlider *frequency;
-(IBAction)change:(id)sender;
@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize frequency;
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    CGFloat fu = frequency.value;
    [self.cro changefreq:fu];
    //NSLog(@"%f",hi.fffff);
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
-(IBAction)change:(id)sender
{
    CGFloat fu = frequency.value;
    [self.cro changefreq:fu];
    //[hi setNeedsDisplay];
}
@end

@interface cro : UIView
@property (nonatomic) CGFloat fffff;
-(void)changefreq:(CGFloat)fre;
@end

@implementation cro
@synthesize fffff;
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        fffff = 15;
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}
-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 1);
    CGContextSetLineJoin(context, kCGLineJoinRound);
    NSLog(@"hi i am here %f",fffff);
    const CGFloat amplitude = 200/2;
    for(CGFloat x = 0; x < 600; x += 0.5)
    {
        CGFloat y = amplitude * cosf(2 * M_PI * (x / 600) * fffff) + 200;
        if(x == 0)
            CGContextMoveToPoint(context, x, y);
        else
            CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, x, y);
    }
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [[UIColor greenColor] CGColor]);
    self.clearsContextBeforeDrawing = NO;
    CGContextStrokePath(context);
}
-(void)changefreq:(CGFloat)fre
{
    NSLog(@"fre= %f",fre);
    fffff = fre;
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

@end
```